# Perl regex matching output from `w -hs` command

Tags: regex, perl, backticks

I'm trying to write a Perl script that will work better with KDE's `kwrited`, which, as far as I can tell, is connected to a [pts](http://linux.die.net/man/4/pts) and puts every line it receives through the KDE system tray notifications with the title "KDE write daemon".

Unfortunately, it makes a separate notification for each and every line, so it spams up the system tray with multiline messages on regular old [write](http://linux.die.net/man/1/write), and for some reason it cuts off the entire last line of the message when using [wall](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wall). One-line messages are also goners.

I was also hoping to make it so that it could broadcast across a LAN with thick clients.  Before starting on that (which would require SSH, of course), I tried to make an SSH-less version to make sure it works.  Unfortunately, it doesn't:

```
perl ./write.pl "Testing 1 2 3"
```

where the following is the contents of `./write.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $message = "";
my $device = "";
my $possibledevice = '`w -hs | grep "/usr/bin/kwrited"`'; #Where is kwrited?
$possibledevice =~ s/^[^\t][\t]//;
$possibledevice =~ s/[\t][^\t][\t ]\/usr\/bin\/kwrited$//;
$possibledevice = '/dev/'.$possibledevice;
unless ($possibledevice eq "") {
    $device = $possibledevice;
}

if ($ARGV[0] ne "") {
    $message = $ARGV[0];
    $device = $ARGV[1];
}
else {
    $device = $ARGV[0] unless $ARGV[0] eq "";
    while (<STDIN>) {
        chomp;
        $message .= <STDIN>;
    }
}

if ($message ne "") {
    system "echo \'$message\' > $device";
}
else {
    print "Error: empty message"
}
```

produces the following error:

```
$ perl write.pl "Testing 1 2 3"
Use of uninitialized value $device in concatenation (.) or string at write.pl line 29.
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
sh: -c: line 0: `echo 'foo' > '
```

Somehow, the regular expressions and/or the backtick escape in processing `$possibledevice` are not working properly, because where kwrited is connected to `/dev/pts/0`, the following works perfectly:

```
$ perl write.pl "Testing 1 2 3" /dev/pts/0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You supply only ONE command line argument (string "`Testing 1 2 3`").

So $ARGV[1] is undef.

So `$device` is undef because of the logic inside `if ($ARGV[0] ne "")` .

So your shell's `echo` command redirects to nothing ("`echo something >`") and thus shell complains (and that's where "undefined $device" Perl warning is from as well).

If you meant the device to be "1", then un-quote your argument string (`perl write.pl Testing 1 2 3`) on command line.

Also, please consider opening $device as a file for writing and printing "$message" to the file handle. It's a bit more idiomatic Perl and less prone to problems stemming from perl-to-shell transitions/quoting/etc...

Comment: Adding more stuff in the argument-processing conditionals fixed it.  The regexes did need some modification, but it works now.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

One problem is your `'` around the attempted system call. No interpolation takes place inside single quotes in Perl.

If you look at a simple case:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;


my $possibledevice = '`w -hs | grep "/usr/bin/kwrited"`'; #Where is kwrited?
print $possibledevice;
```

The output is:

```
`w -hs | grep "/usr/bin/kwrited"`
```

So your shell call never takes place. The fix is to change the shell call to something more like this:

```
my $possibledevice = `w -hs | grep \"/usr/bin/kwrited\"`; #shud b there...
#or
my $possibledevice = qx$w -hs | grep \"/usr/bin/kwrited\"$; #alternate form
```

You can read about the different quote like operators in perlop or at perldoc [HERE](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators)

There is a backtick, system and shell tutorial [HERE](http://sial.org/howto/perl/backticks/)

Comment: I tried that just now, no effect: I get the exact same error.
Something is still wrong with the regexes.

Comment: DVK has the other part of the solution below... You still need to change your shell quotes or nothing will happen.